# Azure MySQL Entity Framework Infrastructure error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure, mysql-connector

I just built an application using Entity Framework and MySQL. Everything works fine in localhost, but when I publish the application and run in the server, I am getting the error:

```
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidCastException: [A]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction cannot be cast to [B]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction. Type A originates from 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in the context 'Default' at location 'D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_6.5.4.0__c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll'. Type B originates from 'MySql.Data, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in the context 'Default' at location 'D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\491e3a19\118d844c\assembly\dl3\ce9fb3e1\00af7a53_1f2ed401\MySql.Data.dll'.
   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.set_DbTransaction(DbTransaction value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Transaction(DbTransaction value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.set_DbTransaction(DbTransaction value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Transaction(DbTransaction value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at TazWorksAPI.Views.ViewModel.CreateRequest.createPackageByName(RequestModel model)
```

Does it say that I have 2 versions of MySQL? How could I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It says you have library mismatch. Some library (ie. EF) tries to use one with version `6.5.4.0` (which exists in Global Assembly Cache of server)
Second one (i.e. your code) tries to use version `6.10.8.0` which is located in your application folder. This probably means, one library has lower requirements to version, and is not present in your local folder (else loading priorities would take local one than from GAC) and second one has your copied dll in scope. You probably need to copy `MySql.Data.dll` closer to library which causes problem.

Comment: The MySQL Connector installed is 6.5.4. I don't have anything for 6.10.8

Comment: `Type B originates from 'MySql.Data, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in the context 'Default' at location 'D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\491e3a19\118d844c\assembly\dl3\ce9fb3e1\00af7a53_1f2ed401\MySql.Data.dll'` 
This is probably coming from your application. Take a look what is created in publish package then.

Comment: I updated the MySQL.Data to the correct version, then I am getting: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file

Comment: @MaxBoy pls do not ask follow-up questions in comments!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following documentation: [ASP.NET Identity: Using MySQL Storage with an EntityFramework MySQL Provider (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider#configure-entityframework-to-work-with-a-mysql-database)

There is a section: [Making project configuration changes to the Web.config file for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider#making-project-configuration-changes-to-the-webconfig-file-for-your-application)

Please ensure all the steps have been followed from that point forward. And, as WueF mentioned earlier: "A big heads up is do NOT use MySQL.Data v.6.10.4. A simple downgrade to 6.9.10 solved me weeks of investigating something I couldn't find."